# What do we call not being behind on time but rather "stuck" or with the times?

Tags: riddle, english

Behind on time, and haven't caught up. No one cares, except those who's time is stuck. Stuck where? Not behind. It's stuck with the times.

mention: it's only 1 word

note: I have no idea what's the answer here, I'm scratching my head with this riddle

Answer (score 2):

Is it a:

> Newspaper?

Behind on time, and haven't caught up.

> If newspapers are old, they can't display new information.

No one cares, except those who's time is stuck.

> No one cares about old information, except for people who are 'stuck' in the past.

Stuck where? Not behind. It's stuck with the times.

> Maybe wordplay here: stuck with the times: many newspapers end with 'times' like the New York Times. [This is why.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16634/why-do-so-many-newspapers-use-the-word-times-in-their-names)